# Should I Write Tests for Argument Exceptions?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

When applying TDD, do you create tests that verify expected exceptions for arguments (ArgumentException, ArgumentNullException, InvalidOperation, etc.) or just ones that are "known", for example, CustomerDelinquentException ?

What about equals, gethashcode overrides? how would i test gethashcode?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really expect an answer other than **"it depends?"** Such as, how much test coverage are you aiming for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always test for any exceptions I throw in my method, including `ArgumentNullException`, `ArgumentException`, etc.  I just find it's best to test these and they're easy to write.  That way if someone ever **removes** those guards, the tests would break and you'd know.

```
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
    public void ToSetOnNullThrows()
    {
        List<string> list = null;
        var target = list.ToHashSet();
    }
```

As far as `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` i test these as well *if you override them*.  For `GetHashCode()` an easy test is to create two equivalent objects (same values used in the hash code) and prove that the hash codes both objects generate are the same.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetHashCodeSameKeysAreSameTest()
    {
        var key = new CompositeKey<string, int>("A", 13);
        var otherKey = new CompositeKey<string, int>("A", 13);

        Assert.AreEqual(key.GetHashCode(), otherKey.GetHashCode());
    }
```

You can *try* to test that two non-equivalent objects return different hash codes, but you'd have to make sure the values you use aren't simply a collision.  This largely depends on the algorithm you code in `GetHashCode()`.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetHashCodeDifferentKeysAreMostLikelyDifferentTest()
    {
        var key = new CompositeKey<string, int>("A", 13);
        var otherKey = new CompositeKey<string, int>("A", 14);

        Assert.AreNotEqual(key.GetHashCode(), otherKey.GetHashCode());
    }
```

For Equals() test that two equivalent objects with the same fields return `true` on `Equals()` and `false` on two non-equivalent objects.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void EqualsTest()
    {
        var key = new CompositeKey<string, int>("A", 13);
        var otherKey = new CompositeKey<string, int>("A", 13);

        Assert.IsTrue(key.Equals(otherKey));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void NotEqualsTest()
    {
        var key = new CompositeKey<string, int>("A", 13);
        var otherKey = new CompositeKey<string, int>("A", 15);

        Assert.IsFalse(key.Equals(otherKey));
    }
```

For even more fun, I like to unit tests `DateTime` dependent stuff too.  This is somewhat harder, but if a method's behavior depends on `DateTime` i still want to unit test them.  So you can create a `DateTime` generator delegate that defaults to returning `DateTime.Now` but have it so that you can set the generator to a specific `DateTime`.  Helps a lot with coverage in my line of work since I'm in the financial industry and a lot of logic depends on pre-market, post-market hours, etc...

```
public class SomeClassThatDependsOnCurrentTime
{
    internal Func<DateTime> NowGenerator { get; set; }

    public SomeClassThatDependsOnCurrentTime()
    {
        // default in constructor to return DateTime.Now
        NowGenerator = () => DateTime.Now;
    }

    public bool IsAfterMarketClose()
    {
        // call the generator instead of DateTime.Now directly...
        return NowGenerator().TimeOfDay > new TimeSpan(16, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Then you just set up a unit test to inject a specific date time.

Comment: +1: I find that thinking about what exceptions the method should throw while writing a test case often helps me to identify corner cases I would not have thought of otherwise.

Comment: @Marco: Added some examples, I can look up an example of the DateTime generator too if you like...

Comment: @James Thank you for such a detailed response! It all makes perfect sense and I actually have a date time generator I use in my apps to account for diff timezones (SystemTime.Now()).

Comment: @Marco: Nice!  A lot of people don't test time dependent methods, which is why i brought it up.  It's really cool once you know the trick though.

Comment: @James I need to checks fields with private setters in my tests, so do you typically result to using reflection to set those in your tests?

Comment: @Marco: That is a point of heavy contention among unit test authors.  Some argue you should never test a private member (that you should only test through the public interface) and others do.  What's your testing toolkit?  Are you using MSTest?  NUnit?  I myself never test private methods.  If i have a piece of sub-logic i want to tests, i either exercise it through the public interface, make it internal and make the test assembly a friend assembly, or completely remove the "internal" functionality into a new class, have the old class call the new class, and then i can unit test the new class.

Comment: @James MSTest. My domain model id is auto-generated from the db, so its got a public getter and private setter.

Comment: @Marco: not sure what model generator you're using, is it possible to grab the interface for the database object and inject behavior using Moq?  I definitely see your delima there.

Comment: @James I'm using Entity Framework, so I actually wrote the class but I do not want to expose write behavior since its an artifact from the database, but used in Equals. I just used the following to setup my conditions and it seems to work. program1.GetType().GetProperty("Id").SetValue(program1, 1, null); I guess I could encapsulate that into another class but now that complicates areas where my entities are materialized back from the db.

Comment: @Marco: That works, also if you right click on your unit test project, select Add Unit Test, it will generate an "Accessor" that does that reflection for you and accesses the field.  For example if your class is Point, it will create Point_Accessor and give you access to the private fields and methods.

Comment: @James Nice, obviously did not know that one!

Comment: Note that this is in MSTest. NUnit offers a more specific alternative to ExpectedException: Assert.Throws. See [Exception Asserts](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exceptionAsserts&r=2.5.10).

Comment: @TrueWill.  Very true.  You can also create your own extension method to mimic Assert.Throws in MSTest as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your code tests arguments and throws exceptions, then yes, you should test for those exceptions. If not or in addition, you should test your code with invalid values to see what happens.

You should test for equals as well, that kind of tests gethashcode too, when you expect two objects to be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Don't forget that unit tests serves as a form of documentation too.  It shows to the next developer or clients using your component the preconditions of the function or method they are calling.